# Pine Script : Percentage change in volume and TP/SL exit not working properly

Tags: pine-script

**Objective**
I’m trying to create a script where it opens a position when there is a user defined volume percentage increase in comparison to 24hrs volume and close that position with user defined TP/SL.

**Example**
If in the present candle there is an increase of 3% volume in comparison to past 24hrs volume then it will open the position and close it with 2% trailing profit or -4% stoploss.

**Problem** 
It opens a long position but for some reason it’s not closing that position at TP/SL and because of that it’s not opening other positions.

[Click here to view the output that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjauT.jpg)

**Please help!!!**

**Code**

```
//@version=3
//study("Intra-bar Volume", overlay=false)
strategy("Volume check", overlay=true)

//Input Time Frame and Bars (288 bars for 24hrs in 5mins time frame)
lower_tf = input("5", title='Lower Timeframe to Assess')
bars_in_tf = input(288, title='Bars of lower Timeframe')-1 // -1 because we count from zero in the loop

//Stoploss and Take Profit inputs
sl_inp = input(2.0, title='Stop Loss %', type=float)/100
tp_inp = input(4.0, title='Take Profit %', type=float)/100

//Backtesting Date Range 
//From Date Inputs
fromDay = input(defval = 1, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
fromMonth = input(defval = 9, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
fromYear = input(defval = 2019, title = "From Year", minval = 1970)

//To Date Inputs
toDay = input(defval = 29, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
toMonth = input(defval = 9, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
toYear = input(defval = 2019, title = "To Year", minval = 1970)

//Calculate start/end date and time condition
startDate = timestamp(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 00, 00)
finishDate = timestamp(toYear, toMonth, toDay, 00, 00)
time_cond = time >= startDate and time <= finishDate

//Calculating 24hrs Volume
buying_volume(range)=>
    vol = na
    for i = 0 to range
        if open[i] < close[i]
            vol := na(vol) ? volume[i] : vol + volume[i]
    vol

lower_buy_vol =  security(tickerid, lower_tf, buying_volume(bars_in_tf))

//Calculating Percentage Change wrt 24hrs Volume
volbuy = (volume/lower_buy_vol)

//Long Entry if Buy Volume is more than 3%
longEntry = volbuy >= 0.03

//SL and TP 
stop_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp)
take_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_inp)

//Submit orders
strategy.entry("Long Entry", true, when=longEntry and time_cond)
strategy.exit("Stop Loss/TP","Simple SMA Entry", stop=stop_level, limit=take_level)

//Plotting the SL/TP line
plot(stop_level, color=red, style=linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(take_level, color=green, style=linebr, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you've set wrong id of the position to exit:

```
strategy.exit("Stop Loss/TP","Simple SMA Entry", stop=stop_level, limit=take_level)
```

So you have an entry id `Simple SMA Entry`, but entry was made with id `Long Entry`. Change it in exit to correct one and it will work:

```
strategy.exit("Stop Loss/TP","Long Entry", stop=stop_level, limit=take_level)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you soo much! :) 
I don't know how I missed it.

Comment: Great! If the answer is helpful, then it'd be nice to mark it as a best answer

Comment: There must be a gray mark under the answer's score which says "click to accept the answer" or something like that. As you click on it it'll become green.